# Why my PAUSE button doesn't stop the MediaPlayer sound?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-mediaplayer, android-button, android-handler

In my stopwatch app I have a **Start** button to start sound, and a **Pause** button to stop or pause sound.

The start and pause of sound works fine if the **Start** button is pressed only once, then it's nicely possible to stop the sound by pressing by **Pause** too.

*But the problem occurs when the **Start** button is pressed more than once. The more I press the **Start** button, the sound runs quicker. And then **PAUSE** button never stops the sound. So, that is a bug!  What thing is causing this and how to solve it in my code?*

[NOTE: The problem only occurs when the START button is clicked more than once]

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button startButton;
    private Button pauseButton;
    private Button resetButton;
    private TextView timerValue;

    private long startTime = 0L;

    private Handler customHandler = new Handler();

    long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
    long timeSwapBuff = 0L;
    long updatedTime = 0L;
    private MediaPlayer mp;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        timerValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timerValue);

        startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);

        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.sound);
                mp.start();
                mp.setLooping(true);

            }
        });

        pauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pauseButton);

        pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {

                timeSwapBuff += timeInMilliseconds;
                customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
                mp.stop();

            }
        });
        resetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reset);


        resetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {

                timerValue.setText("" + 00 + ":"
                        + String.format("%02d", 00) + ":"
                        + String.format("%03d", 00));
                startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                timeSwapBuff = 0;

            }
        });

    }

    private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;

            updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;

            int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
            int mins = secs / 60;
            secs = secs % 60;
            int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
            timerValue.setText("" + mins + ":"
                    + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"
                    + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
            customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
        }

    };
}
```

Comment: There is a difference between stopping a sound and pausing a sound. Please check the `MediaPlayer`'s [lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) for understanding how things work with this type of objects.

Comment: Voicu, i read but i don't get. thats why i want a coded solution for my problem, that i can realize better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code in your stop button.

```
if(mp.isPlaying())
{
mp.stop();
mp.reset();
}
```

if you want to pause your media player

```
if(mp.isPlaying())
{
mp.pause();
}
```

Comment: Sritam Jagadev, thanks for your answer. its very strange that ithis code doesn't make any change in my app. I don't know why. have you gone through my code properly? I think someone really  needs to look at my code. Besieds, I am reading the MediaPlayer lifecycle. One more thing, does it matter if I instantiate my Meadiaplayer outside inside onClick method? does it affect my program? or i should put it outside.